# How to parse text message error to object Error `or` stderr.pipe with color

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, process, spawn

I'm writing a framework I have a problem:

When i use `.pipe` to filter the error message from `runProcess.stderr` of `spawn` i can't find its error message color and it's just white

How can i display error message with color or `parse` message into `Error` object (this error message is Error message of javascript)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of text in the terminal by prepending an ascii color code. For instance `\u001b[31m` would change the text color to red.

```js
console.log("\u001b[31mHello World");
// Will print "Hello World" in red
```

Comment: that didn't work for me. its output is non-fixed text and i want it to have the color as it should be